# Autentificacion sin redireccion Laravel Fortify

Tags: laravel

tengo la siguiente duda: Tengo que conseguir lo siguiente: yo como administrador me logueo al sistema y tengo el permiso para crearles cuentas de acceso a los demas colegas, la autentificacion con Fortify esta funcionando, pero tengo el drama que al crear una nueva cuenta, automaticamente me lleva al home del sitio y aparece logueada la persona a la que le cree la cuenta y no debe pasar eso.
Debo conseguir crear solo yo las cuentas y que cuando las haya creado no halla redireccion y muchos menos se pierda el login actual.

Debo considerar algun tipo de redireccion en especial para subsanar este inconveniente?

Las rutas en mi archivo web.php las tengo asi:

```
 route::get('/register', [RegisteredUserController::class, 'create'])->name('registrar');
route::post('/registerS',[RegisteredUserController::class, 'store'])->middleware(['auth'])->name('cuenta.store');
```

y el form asi:

```
<form id="formCuenta" action="{{ route('register.store') }}" method="POST" > 
                @csrf
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <label for="name" class="form-label">{{ __('Nombre de Usuario') }}</label>
                        <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autocomplete="name" autofocus>
                        @error('name')
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                        </span>
                        @enderror
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <label for="email" class="form-label">{{ __('Correo Electronico') }}</label>
                        <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror"  value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email">
                        @error('email')
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                        </span>
                        @enderror
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <label for="password" class="form-label">{{ __('Ingrese su Contraseña') }}</label>
                        <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" required autocomplete="new-password">

                        @error('password')
                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                            <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                        </span>
                        @enderror
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <label for="password-confirm" class="form-label">{{ __('Confirme Contraseña') }}</label>
                        <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control pa" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <button type="submit" id="btnCuenta" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">
                            {{ __('Crear Cuenta') }}
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <b><span class="text-success" id="success-message"> </span><b>
                </div>
            </form>
```

y el metodo store (propio de fortify) es este:

```
  public function store(Request $request, CreatesNewUsers $creator)/* : RegisterResponse */
    {
        event(new Registered($user = $creator->create($request->all())));

        $this->guard->login($user);

        return app(RegisterResponse::class);

    }
```

Saludos a todos

Comment: Que has intentado al respecto?

Comment: @BetaM hola buen dia, añadi el codigo del form y las rutas que tengo actualmente

Comment: comento que el login y el registro funcionan, pero al crear una cuenta, si vuelvo al home automaticamente veo que esta logueado el usuario que acabo de crear y es lo que debo evitar

Comment: muestranos tu método de creación de usuarios

Comment: Entonces buscas que se haga el registro pero que no haga el login en automático ¿cierto?

Comment: exactamente, cuando yo ingreso con mi usuario y clave me lleva al home del aplicativo, de ahi yo voy a crear otra cuenta, la registro y no deberia hacer el login automatico ya que soy yo quien esta logueado

Comment: Me parece que es derivado de este método `login` perteneciente a la clase `SessionGuard` el cual genera un automático el *log in* del objeto `$user` recién creado. Entonces esa línea la deberías eliminar

Comment: @NicolasAlmonacid solo crea un nuevo `RegisteredUserController` en tu app/Http/Controllers para sobrescribir el metodo `store` y eliminar `$this->guard->login($user)`, aqui una respuesta en ingles a lo que quieres https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64397645